# in Dart, how do i check the value of every input with a specific class?

Tags: events, dart

I have html elements like:

```
<input type="text" id="opening" class="isdouble">
<input type="text" id="closing" class="isdouble">
```

and I want one function that converts the value to a double when `onBlur` is triggered. So I am trying something like:

```
querySelectorAll('.isdouble')
  ..onBlur.listen((e) {
    // get 'this' maybe?
  });
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Don't forget that any time the doc leaves you with doubts you can set a break point and inspect the various objects to understand how things work.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I set a breakpoint inside the onBlur but it suspended on page load, not when the event was triggered, so not much use.

Comment: I just addedcurrenttr 'var evt=e;' inside a blur handler a set a breakpoint on it and it triggered on blur, not onLoad... ? The 'this' you're seeking must be the event target (e.target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument you get in the onBlur listener is `Event e`. This object will hold the event target in its `e.target` property. Therefore, you could do something like this:

```
..onBlur.listen((e) {
    InputElement input = e.target as InputElement;
    input.value = double.parse(input.value).toStringAsFixed(2);
});
```

I'm gonna leave the exception handling up to you :)